# How many JOINs does MySQL8 allow?

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-8.0

I have a query with 287 JOINs inside, and I get "Too high level of nesting for select" from MySQL8.
I can split it in parts, but I don't sure how small they should be.

This post https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,212808,217610#msg-217610 says that limit is 61 JOIN, but it was 12 years ago.

Comment: Are we talking about `JOIN`s in a query, or the number of tables in one `JOIN`?

Comment: If we're talking about number of tables, consider: The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join is 61. This includes a join handled by merging derived tables and views in the FROM clause into the outer query block (see Section 8.2.2.4, “Optimizing Derived Tables, View References, and Common Table Expressions with Merging or Materialization”).

If not, consider this  [How-do-I-override-a-max-limit-of-61-joins-in-a-MySQL-query](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-override-a-max-limit-of-61-joins-in-a-MySQL-query)

Comment: I doubt that any query with so many joins could be proved correct or be maintainable however - 'The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join is 61.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: OK. My question is not about tables, but JOINs. I wonder what limitations MySql has in this case. How can I foresee when "Too high level of nesting for select" occur?